# Reverse data from Fauna DB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-fql, next.js, faunadb

I have been looking at the [docs](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/indexes) indexes for FQL and Fauna DB.  Is there a way to reverse the order of the data returned from the query?

Here is the code I have:

```
q.Map(
  q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index("all_pages")), {
    //! Find way to change order
    size: 3
  }),
  ref => q.Get(ref)
)
```

The [docs](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/indexes) mention the `reverse` flag.

Does anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you have a collection that contains documents with a price field, let's call it ... ermm ... priceables!

Let's add two documents to the collection with price 1 and price 2.

```
[{
  "price": 1
},
{
  "price": 2
}]
```

[Image in UI console of the documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QzOb.png)

### Create a regular index

Create a regular range index on that price value with the following snippet:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "regular-value-index",
  unique: false,
  serialized: true,
  source: Collection("priceables"),
  terms: [],
  values: [
    {
      field: ["data", "price"]
    }
  ]
})
```

### Create a reverse index

There can be multiple values (e.g. a composite index) and the reverse field can be set per value. 
To create a reverse index, set reverse to true for that specific value.

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "reverse-value-index",
  unique: false,
  serialized: true,
  source: Collection("priceables"),
  terms: [],
  values: [
    {
      field: ["data", "price"],
      reverse: true
    }
  ]
})
```

If you go to the UI console and open the index you will notice the values are sorted from highest to low. 
[UI console, reverse index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JAij.png)

I assume that what confused you is that you can't set the reverse boolean in the UI yet. But you can just go to Shell and paste in the FQL code to create the index: [Image of the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G1Ow.png)

Comment: @bajran where do I this function?  I put it in the `client query` and I got an error.

Comment: @bajran I am getting `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: @tithos @brecht-de-rooms showed you how to return results in reverse order, but now you're having problems executing queries, so you should ask about that separately.

Your `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` indicates that your app is emitting some output and then attempting to set HTTP response headers. That's another distinct question.

Answer (score 1):

I just reversed an `Index` successfully. The docs are helpful, but they don't give an example where the `Map` `function` is implemented. The secret is to wrap the `Map` `function` as well, with `q.Reverse`:

```
q.Reverse(
 q.Map(
  q.Paginate(q.Match(q.Index("all_pages")), {
    //! Find way to change order
    size: 3
  }),
  ref => q.Get(ref)
 )
)
```

This should work for you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to reverse the order of data is to use an index, per Brecht's answer. Fauna stores index entries in sorted order, so when your index uses `reverse: true` matching entries from the index are already sorted in reverse order.

WΔ_'s answer is technically correct, but probably not what you want. Using `Reverse` around a `Paginate` reverses the items in the page, but not the overall set. Suppose your set was the letters of the alphabet, and your page size is 3. Without `Reverse`, you'd expect to see pages with `ABC`, `DEF`, etc. If you're trying to change the order of the set, you'd expect to see `ZYX`, `WVU`, etc. WΔ_'s answer results in `CBA`, `FED`, etc.

`Reverse` can operate on a set. So you can `Reverse(Match(Index("all_pages")))`, and `Paginate`/`Map` that result. Note that for large sets, your query might fail since `Reverse` has to operate on the entire set.